# Is $x^3$ a possible solution for a "monic" second order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Is it possible to find two continuous function $p(x), q(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $y=x^3$ is a solution to $$y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0 \quad ?$$

We want to find $p,q$ such that

$$
6x + 3x^2p(x)+ x^3q(x)= 0
$$
If $p$ is any polynomial then it is impossible, and if $p,q$ is continuously differentiable then by using power serieses it is also impossible. So $p,q$ must be merely continuous (on my suspection) if this is true. I strongly doubt it is true, but I cannot give a proof on this.

Comment: If it were true, $q(x)=\frac{6}{x^2}+3p(x)\frac{1}{x}$ would be continuous at $x=0$

Comment: Or write that as $xq(x)+3p(x)=-\frac{6}{x}$ where the left side is obviously continuous and the right clearly not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, if $p$, $q$ are continuous functions, the differential equation
$y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y = 0$ satisfies the hypotheses of the existence and uniqueness theorem, so for any initial condition $y(x_0) = y_0$, $y'(x_0) = y'_0$ there is a
unique solution defined in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ (in fact it turns out that the solution is defined globally, but that's not relevant here).  So from the fact that $y = 0$ is a solution that satisfies the initial condition $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=0$ we can conclude that $y = x^3$, which would satisfy the same initial condition, can't be a solution.